# Does react will convert html snippets set in dangerouslySetInnerHTML to virtual DOM?

Tags: reactjs

I use some DOM string manipulation libraries to generate HTML string and then inject them to some React components using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in my project, does react will add them to the virtual DOM? Can I still get the performance benefits from React in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.  They're represented as string props, and the current html string **as a whole** is compared to the previous string using the equality operator.

There's no checking within the strings, or parsing the html into virtual dom.  You can parse the html yourself, or modify the code generating it to output virtual dom instead.